# Should Python properties use underscores as a name prefix?

Tags: python, properties

Take a look at [this article](https://realpython.com/python-getter-setter/), which explains Python Properties.

(You can access it via archive.ph to get around the paywall.)

In the article the following code is presented:

```
# employee.py

from datetime import date

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, birth_date, start_date):
        self.name = name
        self.birth_date = birth_date
        self.start_date = start_date

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value.upper()

    # ... etc ...
```

Note that in the function `__init__`, `self.name` is initialized **without** an underscore. The same is true for the other attributes, `birth_date` and `start_date`.

However, in the property getter and setters, the variable accessed is names with a preceeding underscore.

`name` -> `_name`

Is this a mistake, or is it intentional? Should the `__init__` function have initialized `_name` instead of `name`?

Comment: this is intentional, it is so that the `name.setter` is called in `__init__` (which ends up assigning to `self_name` anyway). If you did `self._name = name`, then the setter wouldn't be called. try it.

Comment: `name` is a *class* attribute; `_name` is the *instance* attribute used to implement the property bound to `name`.

Comment: Assigning directly to the instance attribute in `__init__` might be seen as an optimization, but I would argue that `_name` is private to the *property*, and `__init__` should go through the property like any other code, so `self.name = name` is the correct version of `self._name = name.upper()`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Aah, that's how it's working. Thanks

Comment: Great comments thanks, please feel free to add answer & I will upvote & accept

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant yes. The whole point of `property` is to give you encapsulation without boilerplate. It can do this because of the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which gives you a hook into attribute access. The idea is you *don't* have to write boilerplate `get_name` and `set_name` methods like you do in, say, Java. Because if you later want to control access to an attribute you can use a `@property` and then all the code that was working with the `instance.name` property will continue to work without breaking the API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two names are intentional, as they refer to two different things:

1. `name` is the *class* attribute bound to an instance of `property`. This instance wraps the getter and setter, invoked as necessary by the descriptor protocol (which we won't talk about further here, other than to say it's how `self.name = ...` invokes the setter rather than creating a new instance attribute that shadows the property).
2. `_name` is the *instance* attribute which the getter and setter use to implement the property.

When you write `self.name = name`, `__init__` is using the property like any other "user" to ensure the assignment to `_name` is made correctly. While it might seem like an optimization to write

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self._name = name.upper()
```

instead of going through the property (after all, your class "knows" how to manipulate `_name` correctly), you now have the uppercasing logic implemented in two different places. It's better to treat `_name` as a private implementation detail of the *property*, rather than the class itself, and *only* access `_name` directly in the getter and setter.

---

Keep in mind that you could define the property outside of the class definition entirely and assign it to the `name` attribute explicitly.

```
@property
def name_property(self):
    ...

@name.setter
def name_property(self, value):
    ...

class Employee:
    name = name_property
    ...

del name_property
```

Doing it inside the `class` statement just makes the assignment simpler (or at least implicit). This helps emphasize that the same property could, theoretically, be used with multiple classes: the property itself doesn't know *which* class `self` might be bound to, and it doesn't really care.

Answer (score -1):

[PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) describe `_single_leading_underscore` as fit for denoting

> weak “internal use” indicator

therefore you might use `_` prefix to convey to users that it should not be assigned directly. Keep in mind that this is only *convention* and does not prevent user from doing so.

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question too well. My question is if the property is called `name` and the field is called `self.name` surely that creates a name clash? `name` is being used twice to mean two different things?